# Posting a multidimensional select array with values

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a page with 50 products displayed. Each product can have up to 4 categories.

This page needs one save button, so I'm trying to figure out how to send 3 pieces of information. The product `id`, all 4 product `categories`, and the category `values`.

When submitting I get:

```
35:Array
88:Array
```

Here is current structure: (keep in mind there will be 50 of these as each product can have 4 categories)

```
<select name="[ PRODUCT ID ][ CATEGORY ONE ]">
<option value="[ CATEGORY ID ]"> CATEGORY NAME </option>
</select>
<select name="[ PRODUCT ID ][ CATEGORY TWO ]">
<option value="[ CATEGORY ID ]"> CATEGORY NAME </option>
</select>
<select name="[ PRODUCT ID ][ CATEGORY THREE ]">
<option value="[ CATEGORY ID ]"> CATEGORY NAME </option>
</select>
<select name="[ PRODUCT ID ][ CATEGORY FOUR ]">
<option value="[ CATEGORY ID ]"> CATEGORY NAME </option>
</select>
```

Here is 2 products worth of code:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['productCat'])){
    foreach($_POST['productCat'] as $a=>$b){
        echo $a.':'.$b.'<br>';
    }
}

?>
<form method="post">
<select name="productCat[35][1]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[35][2]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[35][3]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[35][4]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[88][1]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[88][2]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[88][3]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<select name="productCat[88][4]">
    <option value="[3]">3</option>
    <option value="[4]">4</option>
    <option value="[5]">5</option>
    <option value="[6]">6</option>
    <option value="[7]">7</option>
    <option value="[8]">8</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: Please write what actually is the problem? You state stuff that you use, but not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery for this together with a `data-` attribute so that you easily can collect your data into an object that you're POSTing to the server.

The product ID you can probably store in a GET query variable: `?prodId=43`

```
<select data-category="1">
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery part:

```
var info = [];

$('select').each(function() {
   info.push({
              'category': $(this).data('category'),
              'value': $(this).val()
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
<select name="productCat[35][1]">
<select name="productCat[35][2]">
...
<select name="productCat[88][1]">
<select name="productCat[88][2]">
```

the value of

$_POST[ 'productCat' ]

is actually an array. An array like this:

```
   array( 35 => array( 1 => .., 2 => .., 3 => ..., ... ),
          88 => array( 1 => .., 2 => .., 3 => ..., ... )
        );
```

Thus, your debug output **very reasonable**.

You access the array like this:

```
$_POST[ 'productCat' ][ 35 ][ 3 ] 
$_POST[ 'productCat' ][ 88 ][ 5 ]
```

In general, if a variable (expression) references an array - even an array as part of another array - **just append `[...]` to access this sub-array**.

- $_POST[ 'productCat' ] is the whole bunch returned by your script
- $_POST[ 'productCat' ][ 35 ] are all values of product 35
- $_POST[ 'productCat' ][ 35 ][ 5 ] is the selected value of category 5 of product 35

Comment: How do I access the array in the array?